# Dynamically Add Textfield with tag On button Part-2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I want to add a textfield dynamically with tag so that it can give unique value every time. And than add those values and show on label. When I click button one textfield add "n" give the value, and that value adds to the previous value.

Value adding Successfully. But when I edit anything, change or give another value such as (10 instead of 12) the loop will run again because of this line

```
[Txt_New_Estimated addTarget:self action:@selector(C6Loop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

2nd problem is that when I add a new textfield then the previous textfield did not modify and do not add in rest of textfields... before adding a new textfield it works properly but when edit anything loop will run again.... i want to overCome this problem, so please check this code and give some possible solution. I am sending my code here Please check this code.

```
-(void)CreateTextFeildOnRun
{
if (tag ==0)
{
textPosY = 420;
}
for ( i =tag; i<= tag; i++) 
{
Txt_New_Estimated = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360, textPosY , 130,         65)];
Txt_New_Estimated.delegate = self;
Txt_New_Estimated.text=@"";
//[Txt_New_Estimated setTag:1234];
Txt_New_Estimated.tag = i; 
Txt_New_Estimated.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
[Txt_New_Estimated addTarget:self action:@selector(C6Loop)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
Txt_New_Estimated.placeholder = @"Estimated";
Txt_New_Estimated.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:23];
Txt_New_Estimated.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
Txt_New_Estimated.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[scrollview addSubview:Txt_New_Estimated];

}
}

-(void)C6Loop{
Txt_New_ONU.text=Txt_New_Estimated.text;
[self Calculate2];

}

-(void)Calculate2{
int y14=([Txt_New_Estimated.text intValue]);
y14=n;
n=d;

c14=  y14+([Txt_New_Estimated.text floatValue]);

n  = c14;
[self addest];
}


-(void)addest{

float c1= ([Txt_Engring_Est.text floatValue]) + ([Txt_Weddring_Est.text floatValue]) +      ([Txt_Bridal_Est.text floatValue])+ ([Txt_Veil_Est.text floatValue])+ ([Txt_Shoe_Est.text   floatValue])+n;
Txt_Total_Est.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",c1];
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add those `TextField` when created to to an `NSMutableArray`. something like this:

```
-(void)createTextFieldOnRun
{
    if (tag ==0)
    {
        textPosY = 420;
    }
    for ( i =tag; i<= tag; i++) 
    {
       UITextField *Txt_New_Estimated = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360,textPosY ,130,65)];
       Txt_New_Estimated.delegate = self;
       //....other code..
       [scrollview addSubview:Txt_New_Estimated];
       [textFieldArray addObject:Txt_New_Estimated];
    }
}
```

and when calculating do something like this:

```
int result = 0;
for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray) // will iterate all UITextField which was added
{
    result += [field.text intValue]; //or floatValue
}
NSLog(@"the result is %d", result); //here you have sum of all the text fields' text
```

It doesn't matter whether you change the value or not, it will recalculate all the values.

Comment: gr8 help sir, now my code is working properly , Thank you  very much , but sir now i want to add 5 textfield with different name in "Txt_New_Estimated"  so now how to add these  5 new textfield  in this code  int result = 0;
for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray) // will iterate all UITextField which was added
{
    result += [field.text intValue]; //or floatValue
}
NSLog(@"the result is %d", result); /

Comment: whenever you create `UITextField` add it to array, and when calculating their sum, just iterate through `for` loop as I have done, nothing will be change, except your variable `Txt_New_Estimated`

Comment: again gr8 help sir, now my code working properly as i wanted , Thank You vry much Sir.....

Comment: int result = 0;
for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray) // will iterate all UITextField which was added
{
    result += [field.text intValue]; //or floatValue
}
NSLog(@"the result is %d", result);                                                                                                                               how to iterate 2 different Array in a single loop such as  """for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray) // will iterate all  and  textFieldArray2 in a single loop so that i can pick the value from  same index from both array...

Comment: Are your array with same size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771291/calculate-dynamically-textfield-when-created-to-an-nsmutablearray#comment12435195_9771291