# calculate dynamically TextField when created to an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i am creating the textfield dynamically and adding and subtracting them...

How to calculate and pick the value from two diffrent array on a same loop?

something like that

eg:  for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray && textFieldArray2)

i have to subtract the value and i have 2 Array and i want to subtract the value of two textfield from different array but same index...

My code is

```
int result = 0;
for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray) // will iterate all UITextField which was added
{
result += [field.text intValue]; //or floatValue
}
NSLog(@"the result is %d", result); //here you have sum of all the text fields' text
```

i want to subtract this but both text fields are on different Array but have same index...

```
int y12=([Txt_New_Actual.text intValue]);
float c116= y12-([Txt_New_Estimated.text floatValue]);
Txt_New_ONU.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",c116];
```

Comment: what if count does not match in both arrays ? i.e. in one array 3 elements and in other only 1 ?

Comment: same size and same index but Array diff...  create textfield with tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way. Take one variable to iterate in common as

```
UITextField *fieldArray1=nil,*fieldArray2=nil;
for(int i =0;i<textFieldArray1.count;i++)
{
     fieldArray1 = [textFieldArray1 objectAtIndex:i]; //This is field in array1
     fieldArray2 = [textFieldArray2 objectAtIndex:i]; //This is field in array2 and both are at same index.

     //Do your operation here...
}
```